# Shell-agnostic method to set environment variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Open your favorite search engine and key in "linux environment variable" and you will get thousands of results that say the way to set environment variables is to use `export` or add them to `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/<file>.sh`, or even `/etc/environment`. The problem is, most of these options are dependent on the user using Bash or another shell that will process these files. `/etc/environment` is the outlier, which is set up using Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM). None of these solve my problem.

I need a way to set an environment variable, either for a specific user, or for all users, and have it seen by all programs run by that user/users. This includes shells launched from a terminal emulator, shells launched from an incoming SSh connection, shells provided by the kernel terminal (attached to a tty), or services launched by the init system. I am ok if the method(s) is/are specific to different init systems, but a truly universal method would be much nicer, since this needs to work with minimal modification across multiple distros.